# Triple integral probability problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, probability-theory

We have density functions:

$p_X = e^{-x}$

$p_Y = 2e^{-2y}$

$p_Z = 3e^{-3z}$

We need to find the density function of $p_{x+y+z} $. All three variables are  independent.

Because they are independent I can get the joint probability function by just multiplying them together:

$$p_{X,Y,Z}= p_X \cdot p_z \cdot p_Y = 6e^{-x-2y-3z}$$

My idea is to use triple integral on $x+y+z\leq a$, to find the distribution function, which I would then differentiate to get the desired density function.

$$F_{X+Y+Z}=P(X+Y+Z\leq a)=\iiint_{x+y+z\leq a}6e^{-x-2y-3z}$$

I just don't know how to set the bounds and would need some help.

Comment: If you choose the order $dz ~ dy ~ dx$ - As $x, y, z \gt 0, 0 \lt z \lt a - x - y, 0 \lt y \lt a - x, 0 \lt x \lt a$

Comment: @MathLover So I would do: $\int_0^a\int_0^{a-x}\int_0^{a-x-y}dz dy dx$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way - to use the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) , which is defined as $\phi_X(t)=E[e^{itX}]$.
The remarkable property of this functions is that $\displaystyle \phi_{(a_1X_1+...+a_nX_n)}(t)=\phi_{X_1}(a_1t)...\phi_{X_n}(a_nt)\tag*{}$

Heuristically this is easy to understand: if we want to get PDF for $Y=X_1+...+X_n$, we have to sum up all the possibilities of $X_1X_2...X_n$ with the imposed condition $y=x_1+x_2+...+x_n=\text{const}$.
Using the delta-function representation $\delta(y-a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-it(y-a)}dt$ we get the desired PDF $g(y)$

$\displaystyle g(y)=\int_{0}^\infty ..\int_{0}^\infty f_1(x_1)...f_n(x_n)\delta(y-x_1-x_2 -...-x_n)dx_1...dx_n\tag*{}$

$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt e^{-ity}\int_{0}^\infty ..\int_{0}^\infty f_1(x_1)...f_n(x_n)e^{it(x_1+...+x_n)}dx_1...dx_n\tag*{}$
In our case
$$f_k(x_k)=a_ke^{-a_kx_k}$$
$$a_k\int_{0}^\infty e^{itx_k-a_kx_k}dx_k=\frac{a_k}{a_k-it}$$
$$g(y)=\frac{a_1a_2...a_n}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-ity}}{(a_1-it)(a_2-it)...(a_n-it)}dt$$

The integral can be evaluated, for example, by integrating in the complex plane - adding a big half-circle of the radius $R$ in the lower half-plane (where the poles of the denominator  lie). Given that in this half-plane the denominator declines rapidly at $R\to\infty$, the integral along the half-circle $\to0$.
We going clockwise around the poles, therefore
$$g(y)=-2\pi i\,\frac{a_1a_2...a_n}{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^n\underset{t=-ia_k}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{e^{-ity}}{(a_1-it)(a_2-it)...(a_n-it)}$$
$$=a_1a_2...a_n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{e^{-a_ky}}{\prod_{l=1; l\neq k}^n(a_l-a_k)}$$
For the case $a_1=1; a_2=2; a_3=3$ we get
$$g(y)=1\cdot2\cdot3\bigg(\frac{e^{-y}}{(2-1)(3-1)}+\frac{e^{-2y}}{(1-2)(3-2)}+\frac{e^{-3y}}{(1-3)(2-3)}\bigg)$$
It is easy to check that $\int_0^\infty g(y)dy =1$